# ().is_integer() not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer

Whats wrong with this code:

```
n = 10
((n/3)).is_integer()
```

I do not understand why I cannot set n = any number and check if it is an integer or not.

Thanks for your help!

python 2.7.4

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userh/Arbeitsfläche/übung.py", line 2, in <module>
    print ((n/3)).is_integer()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/userh/Arbeitsfläche/übung.py", line 2, in <module>
    print ((n/3)).is_integer()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'

Comment: Where did you get that is_integer() is a function? Try isinstance(n, int)

Comment: @Max probably from http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer

Comment: @Max thank you very much! I assume isinstance works for various things?

Comment: Reverted your "thanks" edit; please use upvotes to express gratitude instead.

Comment: @tripleee I would if i could....

Comment: @Max is `isinstance(n, int)` better than `n.is_integer()` for some reason?  Please clarify why you are suggesting this, thanks

Comment: @frank Well, other than you've resurrected a 6 year old issue, because not all objects have an is_integer function.  ints don't!

Answer (score 14):

The reason you get this error is because you divide the integer 10 by 3 using integer division, getting the integral number 3 in the form of an `int` instance as a result. You then try to call the method `is_integer()` on that result but that method is in the `float` class and not in the `int` class, just as the error message says.

A quick fix would be to change your code and divide by `3.0` instead of `3` which would result in floating point division and give you a `float` instance on which you can call the `is_integer()` method like you are trying to. Do this:

```
n = 10
((n/3.0)).is_integer()
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using Python 2.7. Unless you use `from __future__ import division`, dividing two integers will return you and integer. `is_integer` exists only in `float`, hence your error.

Answer (score 3):

the other answers say this but aren't very clear (imho).

in python 2, the `/` sign means "integer division" *when the arguments are integers*.  that gives you just the integer part of the result:

```
>>> 10/3
3
```

which means that in `(10/3).is_integer()` you are calling `is_integer()` on `3`, which is an integer.  and that doesn't work:

```
>>> (3.0).is_integer()
True
>>> (3).is_integer()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'
```

what you probably want is to change one of the numbers to a float:

```
>>> (10/3.0).is_integer()
False
```

this is fixed in python 3, by the way (which is the future, and a nicer language in many small ways).

Comment: s/fixed/changed/ - both behaviours are reasonable.

Comment: @glglgl sorry, but no, i strongly don't agree.  a language is a user interface.  if it confuses many users it's bad.

Comment: no its not fixed, same behaviour in 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isdigit, this is a good function provided by Python itself

You can refer documentation here https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

```
    if token.isdigit():
        return int(token)
```

Comment: This answer only works if one is trying to determine if a string is an integer, so it doesn't appear to answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

...

When I wrote this answer there was no information about language.

But in python2 you can use the following to check if it's an integer or not

```
isinstance( <var>, ( int, long ) )
```

Comment: of course, but why do I get this error with is_integer: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'

Comment: well, there is no such function for an int object...the error message says it.

Comment: Dv: in Python 2.7, / is integer division if applied to two integers.